# Error Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException

Tags: zend

Vocês já viram o erro abaixo, quando colocou a app web no servidor Digital Ocean?

> An error occurred during execution; please try again later.
>
> Additional information:
>
> Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException
>
> File:
> /var/www/site.com.br/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php:195
> Message: Zend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager::createFromInvokable:
> failed retrieving "websitecontrolleriteracaousuario(alias:
> Website\Controller\IteracaoUsuario)" via invokable class
> "Website\Controller\IteracaoUsuarioController"; class does not exist
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 /var/www/site.com.br/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(642):
> Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->createFromInvokable('websitecontroll...',
> 'Website\Control...')
>
> #1 /var/www/site.com.br/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(598):
> Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate('Website\Control...',
> 'websitecontroll...')
>
> #2 /var/www/site.com.br/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(530):
> Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create(Array)
>
> #3 /var/www/site.com.br/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php(116):
> Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('Website\Control...', false)
>
> #4 /var/www/lsite.com.br/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/ControllerManager.php(137):
> Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get('Website\Control...',
> Array, false)
>
> #5 /var/www/site.com.br/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(76):
> Zend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager->get('Website\Control...')
>
> #6 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>
> #7 /var/www/site.com.br/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444):
> call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>
> #8 /var/www/site.com.br/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205):
> Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch',
> Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
>
> #9 /var/www/site.com.br/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(314):
> Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch',
> Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
>
> #10 /var/www/site.com.br/public/index.php(28): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
>
> #11 {main}

Comment: Como você publicou essa aplicação lá? Você usou composer? Filezilla? Git? Dê mais informações, por gentileza. Você pode [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/147746/edit) sua pergunta caso seja necessário

Comment: Olá @WallaceMaxters bom dia, meu dev usou  Bitckbucket, ele subiu essa app que estava ok para o servidor Linux da Digital Ocean e deu esse mesmo erro em 3 páginas.

Comment: Sabe se ele rodou o `composer update` após subir esse app? Se ele estiver usando `git`, é provável que a pasta `vendor` não tenha "subido", pois nós desenvolvedores não costumamos colocar ela no repositório.

Comment: Carla, vou formatar esse "trace" do php aí, porque está meio difícil de entender

Comment: @WallaceMaxters vou verificar com ele e volto mais tarde com a resposta, obrigada

Comment: Outra coisa. Verifique se ele desenvolveu o sistema no Windows e, depois, mudou para Linux. Pois estou notando que o nome `websitecontroller` está tudo em minúsculo, porém  em sistemas operacionais Linux, há diferença sensibilidade de maiúsculas ou minúsculas para nomes de pastas. Isso pode gerar erros de "pasta não encontrada"

Comment: Ah @WallaceMaxters ele fez desde o começo em Linux.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters o dev usou sim composer e git

Comment: Se precisar falar comigo no hangouts, podes falar comigo no wallacemaxters@gmail.com